# Angular2 : TypeError 'this.' is undefined

Tags: function, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I wrote a function that gets and shows the "best player" from my array of objects (the player who has most likes). The function works fine and shows me what I want, but the browser shows me errors in the console, and the routing in my app is blocked (I can't navigate between components using routes)

*this is my DashboardComponent Class*

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  bestPlayer:Player;
  data:Player[]=[];
  max:number =0;
  constructor(private playerService : PlayerService ,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.playerService.getData().then(data => {
      this.data = data;
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.data[i].likes>this.max) {
          this.max=this.data[i].likes;
          this.bestPlayer=this.data[i];
        }
      }
    });  
  }

  viewDetails(bestPlayer: Player):void {
    this.router.navigate(['/detail',this.bestPlayer.id]);
  }
}
```

This is my service:

```
import {Player} from './player';
import {PlayersData} from './muck-players';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {
  players:any;
  data:any;
  Player:Player;

  getData():Promise <Player[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(PlayersData);
  }
}
```

when I run the app the browser show me those errors :

> TypeError: this.data[i] is undefined
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

when I delete whats in `ngOninit()` and `viewDetails()` function, routing starts working again and browser doesn't show me errors.

Any help please !

Comment: You are missing the `.then()` closure from `getData()` .

Comment: @Zze thanks for your reply , i added the then() methode to my code and its always the same issue , take a look at the code again i edited the question.

Comment: @HamdiGatri can you share with us your routing config?

Comment: Is there actually any data returning from `getData()` ?

Comment: @Zze yes it really get me the data i want

Comment: @HamedBaatour check out my plunk you will found my app-routing.module.ts page where i configered my routes.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LAam9TvvvEWDX5zyYNQc

Comment: @HamdiGatri check my answer below hope this helps you and if you have any questions I can help! by the way really happy to see a Tunisian interested in angular 4, we can even form an online community if you want where we exchange experiences in the field.

Comment: @HamedBaatour yes i'am in , i'am still a beginner in learning angular but i already loved it . 
And i'am interrested in joining a community of tunisian angular developpers , this is my mail adress hamdigatri92@gmail.com tell me if you want to form a community

Comment: @HamedBaatour, Hello again Hamed , i just created a community in gitter of tunisian angular developers , and i added you to it . 
check it out and invit your friends please :) 
https://gitter.im/Tunisian-Angular-Developers/Lobby#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed dozens of errors in the Plunker and added some missing routing features. The App is working just fine now please take a look at my forked Plunker [over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGISnJwWNLD2d1n87k4B?p=preview)

I fixed all the files paths and used in `forEach` method in your component just like this:

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.playerService.getData().then(data => {
      data.forEach( (arrData) => {
      if (arrData.likes>this.max) {
      this.max=arrData.likes;
      this.bestPlayer=arrData;
      }
    }) 
  });
}
```

Demonstration:

[image]

Comment: waalaikumAlsalam Hamed ,  thanks for your help brother i appreciate that , the app now works fine because of you and all people right here . 
Ramadan Mubarak

Answer (score 3):

As a sidenote, always when you provide a plunker, make sure it's a working one ;) When I got it working, there was only a couple of issue actually. There was nothing wrong with your routing. The first error you were getting

> this.data[i] is undefined

is because of your for loop, you had marked that we should loop until `i` matches the length of the array (or equal). But we need to remember that the index of arrays start with `0`. So the last iteration it was trying to read an index that was not present in your array. So you should add `-1` to your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= this.data.length-1; i++)
```

or do

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++)
```

When this was fixed, it produces new issues. Since data is coming async, so by the time the template is rendered, your variable `bestPlayer` is undefined. This can be fixed with **[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**, or wrapping everything inside a `div` with the condition that `bestPlayer` has values. This need to be applied to both the detail page and the dashboard. With the dashboard:

```
<div *ngIf="bestPlayer">
  <!-- code here -->
</div>
```

And in the detail page the same but using `player` instead, as that is the variable you are using there.

As mentioned, you can also use the safe navigation operator.

These actually cleared the second error you also had.

Here's your fixed **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yExE4yhe2lWn0n6k9gw?p=preview)**.

Comment: thanks alot man for your help , your answer really helped me understand the issues and fixing them. i appreciate that !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi the issue is with your service,

You are trying to loop through data that is not available,

You need to change the code , 
If you are using Observer as service then put you code inside .subscribe method,

If you are using promise then put your looping code inside .then() method.

Try to use this :

If you are returning promise from `this.playerService.getData()` this service

```
this.playerService.getData().then((data) => {
 this.data = data;
 for (var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.data[i].likes>this.max) {
      this.max=this.data[i].likes;
      this.bestPlayer=this.data[i];


  }
})
```

If you are returning observable from `this.playerService.getData()` this service

```
   this.playerService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
     this.data = data;
     for (var i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.data[i].likes>this.max) {
          this.max=this.data[i].likes;
          this.bestPlayer=this.data[i];
      }
    })
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , i tried the promise methode but its the same issue and it show me exact the same errors .
P.S: i added the service in my question take a look

Comment: Then use my .then method and try to console data

Comment: And you can see , what you are missing   then.

Comment: yes i tried it (forget to edit the question) it get me the data i want but it always show me the same errors in the browser console , and it bloc the routing

Comment: Please set the plunker then , I can help you with that.